# React: Is it okay if useCallback returns a value, or is this a bad pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a function called `filterContactsByValue`. It is curried and takes in a value and a list of contacts and then filters the list based on the value and returns the (new) filtered list.

Since the list is often large (10.000+ entries), the web app should run on smartphones and the filter takes into account many values, I want to optimize the computing resources. Therefore I use [`useDebounce`](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce) to not compute unnecessarily.

I also used `useCallback` like this to memoize the computation of the `filteredContacts`:

```
function FilteredContacts({contacts}) {
  const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState('');
  const [value] = useDebounce(filterParam, 800);
  const filterContacts = filterContactsByValue(value.toLowerCase());

  // Is this okay?  ...
  const getFilteredContacts = useCallback(() => filterContacts(contacts), [
    value
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <SearchBar
        value={filterParam}
        onChangeText={setFilterParam}
      />
      // ... and then this? 
      <ContactList contacts={getFilteredContacts()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was wondering whether this is okay, or if returning values like this is bad practice. If it is bad, why and how would you improve it?

**Edit:**
The `filterContactsByValue` function:

```
import { any, filter, includes, map, pick, pipe, toLower, values } from 'ramda';
import { stringFields } from './config/constants';

const contactIncludesValue = value =>
  pipe(
    pick(stringFields),
    map(toLower),
    values,
    any(includes(value))
  );

const filterContactsByValue = pipe(
  contactIncludesValue,
  filter
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce you already have `useDebouncedCallback` hook.

```
const getFilteredContacts = useDebouncedCallback(
    () => filterContactsByValue(value.toLowerCase()),
    800,
    [value]
  );
```

You can also use lodash's debounce or throttle (when you have lodash in your project), but as @skyboyer mentioned you may end with out-of-date callback version(s) will be run after appropriate delay

```
export {debounce} from 'lodash'; 

const getFilteredContacts = useCallback(
    debounce(() => filterContactsByValue(value.toLowerCase()), 1000),
    [value]
);
```

but `useMemo` will be better option, because you don't really want function execution in your render method

```
const FilteredContacts = ({contacts}) => {
    const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState('');
    const [value] = useDebounce(filterParam, 800);
    const contactsFilter = useMemo(
        () => filterContactsByValue(value.toLowerCase()),
        [value]
    );
    const filteredContacts = useMemo(
        () => contactsFilter(contacts), 
        [value, contacts]
    );

    return (
        <div className="main">
            <SearchBar
                value={filterParam}
                onChangeText={setFilterParam}
            />
            <ContactList contacts={filteredContacts} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: btw as far as I can see `useDebouncedCallback` is better since it clears last timer ID if callback is changed(based on `deps`). So while using lodash + `useCallback` may end with out-of-date callback version(s) will be run after appropriate delay.

Comment: `const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState('');
  const getFilteredContacts = useDebouncedCallback(
    () => filterContactsByValue(filterParam.toLowerCase())(contacts),
    800,
    [filterParam]
  );` doesn't work, it throws the error: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`.

Comment: @fard I added the curried version to the question.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback`, like so:

```js
const filteredContacts = useMemo(() => filterContacts(contacts), [
    value
  ]);

...
<ContactList contacts={filteredContacts} />
```

Why? `useCallback` memorizes the creation of a function. Meaning, the reference of the function will be the same, if the diffing parameters are the same. It will STILL be called everytime though, and in your case, won't prevent any compute.

What you want is to only filter your contacts if `value` changes. `useMemo` remembers the last return value of your function, and will only re-run when the diffing parameters change. And they won't change more than once every 800ms, because you debounce it well.

PS: you could use `useCallback` to prevent `filterContacts` from being re-computed for no reason like so:

```js
 const filterContacts = useCallback(() => filterContactsByValue(value.toLowerCase()), [value]);
```

Even tho in your case, the performance gain is tiny.